# Length of audio supported for transcribing audio to text using Google Speech API

Tags: google-speech-api

I want to convert audio to text using google speech api. Google Speech API works perfectly fine for audios less than or equal to 16 seconds, but it does not work for audio length greater 16 seconds.
Any idea on how much long length audio conversion is supported by this API.

Do they support longer length audio conversion if I buy it?

Any pointers are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Speech API documentation, regarding limits: https://cloud.google.com/speech/limits, synchronous requests are limited to <1 minute, while asynchronous requests can be up to 80 minutes in length.